# How to create oneClick setup file with for different version of the target app?

Tags: internet-explorer, installation, toolbar, oneclick

I'm deploying IE's toolbar, having 2 version, one for IE7, and another for IE8, IE9.

I need an installer allow me to check current version of IE, and then run exactly .msi file for each situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a single MSI file which handles all IE versions. Either way, there are multiple setup authoring tools which support what you need.

If you want a free tool you can try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It has a steep learning curve, but it gets the job done.